# Examples of semi-complements

Tags: examples-counterexamples, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

A *semi-complement* (for the purpose of this question) on a poset $P$ is an involution (self-inverse w.r.t. to composition) $\neg : P\to P$, such that:

$$\neg\left(\bigvee_{i\in I} x_i\right) = \bigwedge_{i\in I} \neg x_i$$
 $$\neg\left(\bigwedge_{i\in I} x_i\right) = \bigvee_{i\in I} \neg x_i$$

whenever these suprema / infima exist.

Obviously every Boolean algebra has a semi-complement. Here are some examples, where $P$ is *not* a Boolean algebra:

- the poset $[0\,..\infty]$ with $\neg x := 1/x$, where $\neg 0 = \infty$.
- using the previous example: the poset of functions $X\to [0\,..\infty]$ with $\neg f = 1/f$
- the poset of measurable functions $E \to [0\,..\infty]$ for some measurable space $(E,\mathcal{E})$ with $\neg f = 1/f$
- the "Cheng space construction": Let $L$ be a Heyting algebra and let: 
  $$P := \{(x,y) \in L \times L^{\operatorname{op}} : x\wedge y =\bot\}$$ Then, let $\neg(x,y) = (y,x)$. (I believe this should work possibly with some tweaking, inspired by [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cheng+space))

> What other examples are there of semi-complements?

Comment: You may want to consider ortho-lattices and ortho-modular lattices. I'm not sure those equalities always hold in the infinite case, for these classes, but they certainly hold for many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalizing your examples: they are related to lattice ordered groups, where the involution is $x\mapsto x ^ {-1}$. It's not hard to prove that in any lattice ordered group, $x\mapsto x ^ {-1}$ meets your criteria yet the lattice is not Boolean (l-groups cannot be bounded, for one thing).

This generates wide variety of examples, e.g. $G =(\mathbb Q ^ n, +)$. Or a more exotic one: consider some totally ordered set $\Omega$ and let $G$ be the group of all order preserving automorphisms on $\Omega$ where we define $f\leq g\equiv\forall x: f(x)\leq g(x)$.

Here's an interesting question: suppose we are working with an l-group and some function $x\mapsto x ^*$ meets your criteria. Must $x ^*= x ^ {-1}$? I think the answer is "yes", but I am not sure.

EDIT: answering your comment from below.

I agree that $0,\infty$ are problematic in your first example. I think the most obvious way to relate them to a group is to just drop the problematic elements and look at $(\mathbb R ^ +,\cdot)$, but you could try something like the hyperreal numbers instead. In any case, let's assume you have figure out some way to handle this – then I claim your second example can handle its problematic elements in the same way. Let's say your first example is some group $G$.

Observe that in the case that $| X | = 1$ your second example is exactly the same as the first (do you see why?). More generally, once you handle $0$ and $\infty$ there's a natural isomorphism between your second example and $G ^ {| X |}$ under component-wise multiplication given by $\varphi (f) = (f(x_0), f(x_1),\dots)$. (I.e. your second example is just the direct product of the first example some number of times.)

So, to elaborate on your (correct) point that there are more than 2 problematic elements: if $X =\{1, 2\}$, there are an infinite number of  functions $f_z$ where $f_z(1) = 0, f_z(2) = z$. But clearly $\neg f_z(1) =\neg 0$, where $\neg 0$ is whatever you defined the inverse to be in your first example.

This is why, even though there are an infinite number of elements "without inverses", you only need to handle the two cases from your first example.

Comment: Of course I have not said anything about what I kind of examples I'd expect, so this certainly is an answer. - Though I have a comment: I can see how lattice-ordered groups (almost) generalize the first example (I suppose one can then formally "adjoin" $0$ and $\infty$), but I don't see how this is supposed to work with the other examples, e.g. the set of functions $X\to [0\,..\infty]$ (because $x\mapsto 0$ and $x\mapsto \infty$ are not the only non-invertible elements)

Comment: Well, the inverse you proposed for your second example was the multiplicative inverse, not an inverse under composition. So inverses are the same as in your first example.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplicative inverse" and "the same as in your [my] first example"? Given $f :\{1,2\}\to [0\,..\infty]$ with $f(1) = 0$ and $f(2) = 1$ (e.g.) we have $\neg f(1) = \infty$ and $\neg f(2) = 1$, however $f(1)\cdot \neg f(1) = 0 \neq 1$, hence $f \cdot \neg f \neq 1$. The function $\neg$ is an *extension* of the usual inverse operation (and as I said now there are usually more than just two elements without inverses).

Comment: @Stefan: thanks for the response – I edited the question to answer your comment. If you have further comments, we should probably split this into a new question though.

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right! For some reason I deluded myself into thinking that $\prod_{x\in X} [0\,..\infty]$  and $[0\,..\infty]^X$ are entirely different beasts. Heck if I know how that happend, it's kind of embarrassing actually....

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I'll leave this question open for a few days though to see if I get other responses.